# for loop bounds recalculated each iteration?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, optimization

Suppose you have a class like so:

```
class A {
public:
    A(const size_t m, const size_t n) :
        m_(m), n_(n), data_(m*n ? new double[m*n] : nullptr) {}
    ~A() { delete[] data_; }

    void foo() const {
        // m_*n_ evaluated each iteration?
        for (size_t i = 0; i<m_*n_; ++i)
            data_[i] = 0.0;

        // this probably wont but what about the above?
        for (auto& i : *this)
            i = 0.0;
    }

    double* begin() const { return data_; }
    double* end() const { return data_ + m_*n_; }

private:
    size_t m_, n_;
    double* data_;
};
```

Since foo is const and m_,n_ are member variables, the compiler should know that these cannot change. Is the product evaluated each time or does the compiler optimize this away?

Comment: it depends on the compiler, on its specific optimization settings, on the relatice position of Mars and Moon, etc. **But does it really matter?** Have you found by benchmarking that this is a significant bottleneck in your code? If not, just don't bother.

Comment: You could always look at the assembly and see what it is doing.

Comment: Actually, the compiler should see that `m_` and `n_` do not change during the loop and hoist that computation out of the loop.

Comment: Why not just do the computation before the loop and send the result to another variable which is then used for the loop bound? That way you can be 100% sure your compiler does not recalculate the product on each iteration. I do not know if the compiler does recalculate or not, but i do know that if you have use a string length function to determine the length and this is in the loop bounds, such like `for(int i=0; i<strlen(mystring); i++)`, the compiler will recalculate the string length each time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [loop condition evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242185/loop-condition-evaluation)

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

```
   // m_*n_ evaluated each iteration?
    for (size_t i = 0; i<m_*n_; ++i)
        data_[i] = 0.0;
```

Answer: Probably, but you never know. Compilers are getting pretty clever.

You could improve the odds a lot by declaring `m_` and `n_` to be `const` members. You should do that anyway, IMHO, because the logic of that class requires it; if `m_` or `n_` change, then `data_` needs to be reallocated. Declaring the variables as `const` tells the compiler that even if it can't see all the definitions of all the member functions of the class, it is allowed to assume that `m_` and `n_` don't change.

Question 2:

```
    for (auto& i : *this)
        i = 0.0;
```

In this case, the end value will *not* be recomputed, by definition. That is how the range for statement is defined.

In general, there is a considerable difference between:

```
 for (auto p = container.begin(), lim = container.end();
      p != lim;
      ++p) { ... }
```

and

```
 for (auto p = container.begin();
      p != container.end();
      ++p) { ... }
```

In the first case, the assumption is that the container is not modified during the loop, since a modification will invalidate iterators (such as the `lim` iterator). (There are some container types for which this is not true. But for most container types, modification should be avoided during loops.)

In the second case, the limit value is computed every time, so if the container is modified there is no problem. At least, there is no problem with the end test. You still need to ensure that `p` cannot be invalidated, and for some container types -- unordered maps and sets, for example -- the sequence of elements can be altered by a modification, so adding a new element might cause some elements to be missing from the iteration.

The range for syntax `for ( variable : expression)` is explicitly defined to be translated into the first of the above iteration styles, where the limit is computed once at the beginning of the iteration, and consequently mutations which might invalidate the limit iterator result in undefined behaviour.

In most cases, you should avoid such mutations and you should use the range syntax or the equivalent style. But there are applications in which recomputing the limit each time is appropriate. Probably the best example of such a use-case is a worklist, which can be modeled with a `std::deque`:

```
for (auto work = workqueue.begin();
     work != workqueue.end();
     ++work) {
  /* ... */
  if (some_condition) {
    work_queue.emplace_back(work_item);
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

That's a common style in graph algorithms, for example.