# Is there any benefit to this combination of pointers and loops?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm working through CUDA C Programming by Cheng, and came across this piece of code:

```
void sumMatrixOnHost (float *A, float *B, float *C, const int nx, const int ny) {
    float *ia = A;
    float *ib = B;
    float *ic = C;
    for (int iy=0; iy<ny; iy++) {
        for (int ix=0; ix<nx; ix++) {
            ic[ix] = ia[ix] + ib[ix];
        }
        ia += nx; ib += nx; ic += nx;
    }
}
```

This is for matrix addition whereby the matrices are stored in a row-major format.

As I understand, the inner for loop is iterating over a row and performing element addition, and the outer for loop is then used to increment the pointers to the start of the next row.

Why is this approach better than using pointers over the whole matrix, i.e.

```
for (int i=0; i<ny*nx; i++) {
    ic[i] = ia[i] + ib[i];
}
```

or dual for loops, i.e.

```
for (int iy=0; iy<ny; iy++) {
    for (int ix=0; ix<nx; ix++) {
        ic[iy*nx+ix] = ia[iy*nx+ix] + ib[iy*nx+ix];
    }
}
```

Is this something to do with how it is optimized by the compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach, is always the best approach:

```cpp
for (int i=0; i<ny*nx; i++) {
    C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
}
```

This will be faster than the first solution. The problem with splitting the matrix up by row, is that the vectoriser will do:

- process line in batches of 32bytes (size of YMM)
- Process the remaining handful of values at the end of the line.
- Now repeat for each line!

If however you do it with a single loop, the code generated will be:

- process all data in batches of 32bytes (size of YMM)
- Process the remaining handful of values at the end of the matrix that don't align to 32byte blocks.

The first version just adds pointless code to process the inner loop. None of that code is needed, it just breaks the ability to vectorise the entire matrix.

Answer (score 2):

The approach on sumMatrixOnHost is better for optimization, and it should execute faster (generally) then the two approach you have suggested.

For the alu multiplication takes more time than addition. 
So in sumMatrixOnHost there is no multipicaion, in

```
for (int i=0; i<ny*nx; i++) {
    ic[i] = ia[i] + ib[i];
 }
```

there is multiplication in each iteration of the loop.
in

```
for (int iy=0; iy<ny; iy++) {
    for (int ix=0; ix<nx; ix++) {
        ic[iy*nx+ix] = ia[iy*nx+ix] + ib[iy*nx+ix];
    }
}
```

there are 3 multipication in each iteration of the loop.

A simpler approach can be

```
 int n = ny*nx;
 for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    ic[i] = ia[i] + ib[i];
 }
```

but in the last approach we lose another thing that is good in sumMatrixOnHost, and that is the ability to do the operation on matrix blocks and not the whole matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the response, good point about the repeated multiplication - would the compiler optimise it to that? I.e. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242185/loop-condition-evaluation) When you say `do the operation on matrix blocks' do you mean say do the operation on only a select number of rows? It doesn't seem that we would want that often because this is specifically for matrix addition, which is of the whole matrix?

Comment: The optimization depends on the compiler, I know that if you run 'gcc -o' it will probably optimize that, but not all compilers will. I guess that whoever wrote that code wanted to be sure it will optimized correctly on every compiler, which is very important if this is going to be a c library and not a specific program.
About the matrix blocks, somtimes in linear algebra you don't want to do the operation on the whole matrix because maybe one matrix is smaller, maybe it just a vector, maybe you already know that half of the matrix is just zeros (and so on).